# In GeoServer Failed to create SQL view: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object

Tags: geoserver, postgresql

I am getting this error

> Failed to create SQL view: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object

in every 10 - 15 minutes while creating a layer via `Create new SQL view` in GeoServer, or while previewing the layer after getting this error.

The operating system is `CentOS Linux 8.4.2105`

JVM Version is `Red Hat, Inc.: 11.0.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)`

```
General information about GeoServer; 
Build Information
GeoServer Version
2.20.0
Git Revision
b1f638457da904c217b00b859f66fae02e797786
Build Date
13-Oct-2021 08:18
GeoTools Version
26.0 (rev eadab668a9813bf253a151795ed3e38014acf288)
GeoWebCache Version
1.20.0 (rev 1.20.x/d7c7f26f15eca11d49f4d1fca579f123fde69741)
```

It is connected to Postgres database v. 14

Geoserver Logfile is as follows

```
28 Oct 16:59:28 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] -
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Rendering process failed. Layers: Crop_advisory_english
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:589)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:202)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:82)
        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:344)
        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:203)
        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:113)
        at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:250)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor424.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:38)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:57)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:32)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:62)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:41)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:51)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.getMap(Unknown Source)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor385.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:869)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:271)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1452)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.createConnection(JDBCDataStore.java:2147)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getConnection(JDBCDataStore.java:2089)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getConnection(JDBCDataStore.java:2119)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:580)
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeatureSource.java:635)
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:169)
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:52)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.drawPlain(StreamingRenderer.java:2651)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2286)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:917)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:540)
        ... 139 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:114)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.geotools.data.jdbc.datasource.AbstractManageableDataSource.getConnection(AbstractManageableDataSource.java:42)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.createConnection(JDBCDataStore.java:2131)
        ... 149 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1134)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
        ... 152 more
28 Oct 16:59:28 DEBUG [org.geoserver.filters] - Not compressing output for mimetype: image/png
28 Oct 16:59:28 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
28 Oct 16:59:31 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 16:59:31 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 269us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 16:59:36 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 16:59:36 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 278us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 16:59:41 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 16:59:41 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 263us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 16:59:46 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 16:59:46 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 267us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 16:59:51 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 16:59:51 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 262us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 16:59:56 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 16:59:56 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 258us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:01 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:01 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 280us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:06 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:06 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 260us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:11 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:11 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 258us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:16 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:16 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 275us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:21 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:21 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 263us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:26 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:26 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 257us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:31 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
28 Oct 17:00:31 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 252us for /usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/gwc-layers
^C2021-10-28 17:00:32.148:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:JettyShutdownThread: Stopped ServerConnector@480d61fc{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2021-10-28 17:00:32.148:INFO:oejs.session:JettyShutdownThread: node0 Stopped scavenging
2021-10-28 17:00:32.149:INFO:oejshC.geoserver:JettyShutdownThread: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
2021-10-28 17:00:32.151:INFO:oejshC.geoserver:JettyShutdownThread: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
28 Oct 17:00:32 WARN [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter] - Destroy method 'destroy' on bean with name 'gwcMemoryBlobStore' threw an exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@4333b91b[Not completed, task = org.geowebcache.storage.blobstore.memory.MemoryBlobStore$BlobStoreTask@47f6b5c5] rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1f193416[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
28 Oct 17:00:32 WARN [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter] - Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'geoServerLoader': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'geoWebCacheExtensions': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
2021-10-28 17:00:33.095:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:JettyShutdownThread: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@799f10e1{GeoServer,/geoserver,null,STOPPED}{/usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver}
```

Once the timeout happens, the GeoServer shuts down, so I have to manually restart the services again.
How to rectify this error?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Hii @IanTurton, I can see these 5 options in Global Settings page of GeoServer viz;  DEFAULT_LOGGING.properties , GEOSERVER_DEVELOPER_LOGGING.properties, GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING.properties, PRODUCTION_LOGGING.properties, VERBOSE_LOGGING.properties. Should I check GEOSERVER_DEVELOPER_LOGGING.properties?

Comment: either of the developer settings will show you the actual connection being used.

Comment: @IanTurton I have checked the geoserver_developer_logging.properties, and updated the log output generate in the question, however I’m not sure about the cause of timeout. In the meantime the web pages keep on changing as if I want to go to styles or layer preview or stores, but the layers do not load and timeout error pops up.